# Database values revert back after session.commit()

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having an issue where some data appears to be reverting back to it's original values after session.commit() has been called.
Here's the code that I'm running currently:

```
def delete_source(source_id):
    source = Source.query.get_or_404(source_id)
    tasks = Task.query.all()

    log.info_print(f"source_id = {source_id}")

    log.info_print(f"Before commit [1]: {tasks}")

    for task in tasks:
        if source_id in task.source:
            task.source.remove(source_id)

    log.info_print(f"Before commit [2]: {tasks}")
    db.session.delete(source)   

    db.session.commit()
    log.info_print(f"After commit [1]: {tasks}")
```

And the output is as such:

```
source_id = 42
Before commit [1]: [Task('ID: 1', 'Source: [42, 15]')]
Before commit [2]: [Task('ID: 1', 'Source: [15]')]
After commit [1]: [Task('ID: 1', 'Source: [42, 15]')]
```

A note on the goal here...
when this route is called, it deletes an item with the source_id from the Source database table using `db.session.delete(source)`, however this still leaves the source_id within the Task table (specifically within the Source array), so that's why I have the `for task in tasks` loop that removes it from the source array.

It is successful in removing the value from the array as is demonstrated in the `Before commit [2]` log entry. But then for some reason it's coming back. But the deleted source doesn't (which it's not supposed to, of course!)

Looking forward to some suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the docs but I'm not too familiar with sqlalchemy so I didn't find much. One theory is that the `Query` object created by `tasks = Task.query.all()` detected that you'd committed new changes to the database, and automatically re-computed `tasks` the next time you used it - in this case, when you printed it in that post-commit log message. This newly generated `tasks` returned from the database would then still have the removed source stored within its source array.

One parameter I came across for for `Session` objects was called `expire_on_commit`. The docs for `Session.commit()` say (emphasis mine):

> By default, the Session also expires all database loaded state on all ORM-managed attributes after transaction commit. **This so that subsequent operations load the most recent data from the database.** This behavior can be disabled using the expire_on_commit=False option to sessionmaker or the Session constructor.

I'm not sure if referencing a `Query` result is considered a "subsequent transaction", but i'ts possible. Like I said, I don't know a ton about sqlalchemy so this flag might not actually be relevant to this particular situation, and this whole theory of `tasks` getting re-computed might be totally off-base, but I figured I'd share what I found in case it proves helpful.

You can read more about Session and the commit method here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.commit

Comment: I definitely had thought that too.
So I removed the `source = Source.query.get_or_404(source_id)` and the `db.session.detele(source)` so that it does the Task query only.
And still, it's not seeming to update as expected :/ hmmm.

Comment: Removing those two lines you mentioned theoretically wouldn't affect the way Tasks is computed right? Since deleting the `Source` doesn't actually affect the Tasks table. Did you try setting `expire_on_commit` to False when you created your `Session`?

Comment: Correct, removing those two lines has no impact on tasks/Task. But it eliminates the possibility that the two are competing in any way. I also set `expire_on_commit to False`, however that hasn't changed the result at all (with and without the source/Source code in there). Still seems to revert back to the pre-deletion value.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and found the solution for myself. I found this question during my research and wanted to answer it since it is still not truly answered. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72861174/17555759 is my post with my answer.

I believe that what you need to do is to manually re-create the many-to-many key. Here is the code that I used to resolve my version of this issue:

```
        UserPost.query.filter_by(post_id=post_id).delete()
        for a_id in author_ids:
            user = User.query.get(a_id)
            db.session.add(UserPost(user_id=a_id,post_id=post_id))
```

Here I dropped the UserPost (the many to many relationship table) entries that defined the relationship between the User and Post models. Then I added a new entry manually using the ids for the Post and User that I wanted to associate. It seems that SQLAlchemy does not cascade things like this automatically.

What I believe is fundamentally happening is that when we remove the relationship entry in just the Tasks model, we put the database in an inconsistent state. When db.session.commit() is called, the data is expired and refreshed, which in turn causes the data in the M2M model to be re-applied to the individual Tasks again, rather than persisting our change to the Task model across the relationship models.