# relationship database changes revert after db.session.commit()

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am having trouble with some odd behavior in my code.

I am writing an API route to update some database data for blog posts when a PATCH request is received.

I am updating a few fields - 'users', 'tags', and 'text'. tags and text are updating exactly as expected, but the users associated with a given post is defined as a many-to-many relationship using the `db.relationship()` sqlalchemy method.

When I change the value of Users, it is reflected properly in `print(post)`. As soon as I call `db.session.commit()`, however, any subsequent checks to this data reflect the original data. E.g. if I update users to [1,3], any calls to post will reflect users = [1,3] until db.session.commit() is called, at which point the data will revert to users = [1,5] (or whatever the original value was).

Models:

```
User:
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column("password", db.String, nullable=False)
    salt = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship("Post", secondary="user_post", viewonly=True)

Post:
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "post"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    likes = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0, nullable=False)
    reads = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0, nullable=False)
    popularity = db.Column(db.Float, default=0.0, nullable=False)
    users = db.relationship("User", secondary="user_post", viewonly=True)

    # note: comma separated string since sqlite does not support arrays
    _tags = db.Column("tags", db.String, nullable=False)

    @staticmethod
    def get_post_by_post_id(post_id):
        return Post.query.get(post_id)

UserPost:
class UserPost(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user_post"
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post.id"), primary_key=True)
```

Relevant code:

```
@api.patch('/posts/<post_id>/')
def update_post(post_id):

[...] User validation and such.

post = Post.get_post_by_post_id(post_id)

[...] # a whole bunch of data cleaning and error handling code

    if author_ids is not None: #author_ids contains a list of integers
        new_users = []
        for a_id in author_ids:
            user = User.query.get(a_id)
            new_users.append(user)
        post.users = new_users

    if tags is not None:
        post.tags = tags

[...] # other 'if _ is not None:' blocks

    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify({"post":post.serialize(withUsers = True)}),200
```

Sample Output:

```
request: <Request 'http://localhost/api/posts/1' [PATCH]> {'authorIds': [1]}
unmodified post
 -----Post-----
ID: 1
Text: Excepteur occaecat minim reprehenderit cupidatat dolore voluptate velit labore pariatur culpa esse mollit. Veniam ipsum amet eu dolor reprehenderit quis tempor pariatur labore. Tempor excepteur velit dolor commodo aute. Proident aute cillum dolor sint laborum tempor cillum voluptate minim. Amet qui eiusmod duis est labore cupidatat excepteur occaecat nulla.
Likes: 12
Reads: 5
Popularity: 0.19
Tags: ['food', 'recipes', 'baking']
Users: [<User 2>, <User 1>]
--------------
post within author_ids conditional:
 -----Post-----
ID: 1
Text: Excepteur occaecat minim reprehenderit cupidatat dolore voluptate velit labore pariatur culpa esse mollit. Veniam ipsum amet eu dolor reprehenderit quis tempor pariatur labore. Tempor excepteur velit dolor commodo aute. Proident aute cillum dolor sint laborum tempor cillum voluptate minim. Amet qui eiusmod duis est labore cupidatat excepteur occaecat nulla.
Likes: 12
Reads: 5
Popularity: 0.19
Tags: ['food', 'recipes', 'baking']
Users: [<User 1>]
--------------
post after all conditionals:
 -----Post-----
ID: 1
Text: Excepteur occaecat minim reprehenderit cupidatat dolore voluptate velit labore pariatur culpa esse mollit. Veniam ipsum amet eu dolor reprehenderit quis tempor pariatur labore. Tempor excepteur velit dolor commodo aute. Proident aute cillum dolor sint laborum tempor cillum voluptate minim. Amet qui eiusmod duis est labore cupidatat excepteur occaecat nulla.
Likes: 12
Reads: 5
Popularity: 0.19
Tags: ['food', 'recipes', 'baking']
Users: [<User 1>]
--------------
post after commit:
 -----Post-----
ID: 1
Text: Excepteur occaecat minim reprehenderit cupidatat dolore voluptate velit labore pariatur culpa esse mollit. Veniam ipsum amet eu dolor reprehenderit quis tempor pariatur labore. Tempor excepteur velit dolor commodo aute. Proident aute cillum dolor sint laborum tempor cillum voluptate minim. Amet qui eiusmod duis est labore cupidatat excepteur occaecat nulla.
Likes: 12
Reads: 5
Popularity: 0.19
Tags: ['food', 'recipes', 'baking']
Users: [<User 2>, <User 1>]
--------------
```

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083696/update-value-in-sqlalchemy-many-to-many-association-table) SO post, I believe I am writing the code that SHOULD do what it I am asking it to.

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62420648/database-values-revert-back-after-session-commit) SO post, another person had this same issue a few years ago and never got a proper response.

I am sure I am misunderstanding something about this functionality, but so far I am at a total loss as to what I could change to get this to work properly.

Comment: What does `Post.get_post_by_post_id()` look like?

Comment: @Henry Added under the Models: Post: section.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I had to change my conditional block to:

```
    #actually do the changes needed now that all data is verified.
    if author_ids is not None:
        UserPost.query.filter_by(post_id=post_id).delete()
        for a_id in author_ids:
            user = User.query.get(a_id)
            db.session.add(UserPost(user_id=a_id,post_id=post_id))
```

in order for it to work properly. I believe that the way I was doing it was changing only the relational model on the Post field, and then was reverting when it expired and refreshed the object after the commit() call.

Comment: A common mis-step is to clone the code for working with an association *table* and try to apply it directly to working with an association *object*. In your case, using an association *table* (as per the first answer you cited) would work because you are not tracking anything other than the foreign keys in the user_post table. However, if you did need to track additional attributes in that table (and hence use an association *object* as you are doing) then consider an [association proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects).

Comment: Yes, the root of this project is doing a programming interview take home project, so it's my first time muddling through sqlalchemy. Thank you for your clarifying post. It makes more sense to me now where I went wrong.